# How to return multiple queryset object or add queryset result from get_queryset method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my django application i have defined a ViewSet which has a get_queryset method as this :

```
class SampleViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorizedToAccess, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by=self.request.user.id)
        queryset1 = Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by!=self.request.user.id) 
        return queryset
```

This way i have two queryset objects 1st where samples are submitted by the user and 2nd where samples which are submitted by other users.
This SampleViewSet is called from an ajax request where i use the returned queryset object.

Can you please help how can i return both the objects.

For what i tried is i print the queryset object and tried fooling django by creating json object similar to the queryset.But it seems like django is quite intelligent in catching that.

EDIT: The question is should i look for an alternate method  of get_queryset like list() [From Django Rest framework ] and return the json      with Httpresponse or is there a real solution to either club two queryset object and return from here.

Comment: What's the final result you're trying to achieve? Get these two querysets chained together and rendered as a single JSON list?

Comment: I want to get two separate list of samples(from the queryset) one submitted by the user and 2nd which are submitted by other users.

Comment: Sure, but what you gonna do with them next? Could you show us a sample "ideal" JSON?

Answer (score 5):

Until the author hasn't refined the question, the first guess is:

```
from itertools import chain

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by=self.request.user.id)
    queryset1 = Sample.objects.filter(submitted_by!=self.request.user.id) 
    return chain(queryset, queryset1)
```

Comment: Extremly soory for being late , as i lost my net connectivity. Once i return queryset and queryset1 from here, i want to access these two separatly.i.e if i chain these two objects, is there any way i can unchain them. i will be using them in a Javascript file.

Comment: @AmanGupta if you got the solution then please comment here.I also want to return two queryset objects by get_queryset but unable to do so.

Answer (score 2):

without `chain` you can manage like this:

```
def list(self, request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    server = Server.objects.all()
    serializer1 = self.serializer_class(server, many=True)
    serializer2 = self.serializer_class(client, many=True)
    Serializer_list = [serializer1.data, serializer2.data]
    return Response(Serializer_list)
```